# Conceito de component no Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Bom, comecei a estudar **Angular** (2 e 4) e fiquei meio perdido em alguns momentos, o **"component"** tão citado como algo essencial me confundia bastante. Afinal qual o conceito ou o que é um component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um componente é uma "versão" simplificada de uma [diretiva](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), que basicamente são marcadores ou extensões de elementos que compõem o [DOM](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_de_Objeto_de_Documentos), estes marcadores informam ao AngularJS para inserir alguma funcionalidade específica a esse elemento.

Uma das principais vantagens do uso de componentes é criar trechos de códigos reaproveitáveis de maneira trivial, o que substitui a criação de diretivas com configurações mais complexas.

Segue um exemplo de como um componente funciona na prática: [plunker component](https://plnkr.co/edit/BK3BveMhflJKv6BJIbPD?p=preview)

---

Referências: [docs.angularjs components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component), [usando-component-no-angular-1-5](https://cezarcruz.com.br/usando-component-no-angular-1-5/)